# multiple sending ios push notification doesn't work

Tags: php, ios, push-notification

I get a customized CMS for school (PHP/Mysql/html/CSS/JS). One of the functions in this CMS is sending school info to the mobile applications. For example a teacher can add news for his students and the CMS sends android and iOS push notifications to his students.

The problem is when the system sends multiple iOS notifications, the notifications are not received. (Single iOS notifications work without problem).

The source code of the function:

```
function send_notification_ios($mesaj, $uye, $link = NULL,$cert = 'combined',$passphrase="passphrase123") {
    $success = 0;
    $failure = 0;
    $error;
    $errorString;
    $keyPath = dirname(__FILE__) . '/' .$cert.'.pem';

    $keyPassword = $passphrase;
    $context = stream_context_create();
    if (!stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'local_cert', $keyPath)){
        return json_encode(array('success' => 0, 'failure' => 1, 'reason'=>'stream_context local_cert'));
    }
    if(!stream_context_set_option($context, 'ssl', 'passphrase', $keyPassword)){
        return json_encode(array('success' => 0, 'failure' => 1, 'reason'=>'stream_context passphrase'));
    }

    $socket = stream_socket_client('ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195', $error, $errorString, 60, STREAM_CLIENT_CONNECT|STREAM_CLIENT_PERSISTENT, $context);
    if (!$socket) {
        return json_encode(array('success' => 0, 'failure' => 1, 'reason'=>'soket: '.$error.' '.$errorString.' '.$keyPath.' '.$keyPassword));
    }
    $body['aps'] = array(
            'alert' => array( 
                'action-loc-key'    => "Open",
                'body'              => $mesaj
            ),
            'sound' => 'default',
            'badge' => 0
        );
    foreach ($uye as $item) {
        $body['aps']['badge'] = (isset($item['badge'])) ? $item['badge'] : 0;
        $body['url'] = (isset($item['url'])) ? $item['url'] : '';
        $encodedData = json_encode($body);
        $binaryString = chr(0).pack('n', 32).pack('H*', $item['apikey']).pack('n', strlen($encodedData)).$encodedData;
        $result = fwrite($socket, $binaryString, strlen($binaryString));
        if (!$result) {
            $failure++;
        } else {
            $success++;
        }
    }
    fclose($socket);
    return json_encode(array('success' => $success, 'failure' => $failure, 'reason'=>'fwrite', 'certname'=>$cert));
}
```

Any help will be appreciated.

Comment: Sending push notification in multiple devices you need to pass all the device tokens which need to receive push notification.

Answer (score 0):

There are two types of certificates for sending push notification.

1. Development Push Notification Certificate - This works when when you work in development.
2. Distribution Push Notification Certificate - The production push will work when you download the app from the App Store. You can also test the production push with an AdHoc build of the app

[Simple way to test iOS push notifications](https://github.com/jPaolantonio/SimplePush/blob/master/simplepush.php)

You need to add device token and your certificate with passphrase .

Comment: As I wrote, single push notification works.So it's not certificate issue.

Comment: Your certificate should be Distribution Push Notification Certificate (.pem file)  `ssl://gateway.push.apple.com:2195` should be the URL